# How to have a Batch File create a shortcut on desktop

Tags: batch-file

I am creating a program that fixes ALL issues with Windows Update. I need to make this program create a shortcut on the desktop. I am using Iexpress.exe. I will be installing this on many computers with different user account names. I cannot specify the user account if I type in the file path like C:\Users\%Cannot specify user%\Desktop.

Comment: So use the `%USERNAME%` variable

Comment: ... or even `%USERPROFILE%`

Comment: You should make sure you are using an installation method which correctly determines the 'shared/common/public/all users' desktop directory, _(CSIDL_COMMON_DESKTOPDIRECTORY)_. For that it would also probably need to run 'elevated/as administrator'. Choose the installation methods according to their ability to perform the tasks you need, not selecting a packager and scripting language then trying for force them to perform those tasks.